# How to display HTML tags as text

Tags: html

How can I display HTML tags in a `.html` page without having my browser try to execute whatever is in the tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must use use the escaped version.  For example `<` becomes `&lt;` (no quotes) and `&` becomes `&amp;`.

You should be able to find a full list of transformations.

An example snippet:

```
&lt;a href="http://google.com"&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;
```

is the escaped version of:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Edit:

The standard's list of entities: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html

A Wikipedia artcile on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Please note that, unless you're not using UTF-8 for some ungodly reason, the only entities in that list that should ever be used are: `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`, `&apos;`, & `&quot;`.

Comment: That's a good point, @AndrewMarshall.  I didn't even think about pointing out that escaping anything that can be escaped is not always necessary :).  And no problem MonuMan5.  Glad I could help.

Comment: The only characters that need to be escaped to show HTML code as text are strictly “<” and “&”. Escaping “>” is not needed, though people may do that for symmetry. The rest of the answer does not relate to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function "`highlight_string();`" 
like this:

```
<?php
highlight_string('<?php phpinfo(); ?>');
?>
```

It will output the input as a string with colorcoding. 
check out its php documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php

Answer (score -2):

The answer for inserting tags in the body part can be gone through `<textarea>` tag.The text or tags entered between the opening & closing `<textarea>` tag will be shown as such.

Comment: In addition to other drawbacks (like using an input element where no input is expected), this only deals with tags, not character references; e.g., `&eacute;` is not rendered as such but interpreted as “é”.