# HTML <code> tag with HTML in it

Tags: html

I am trying to surround HTML code with `<code></code>` but it doesn't do what it is supposed to do. It display the page like it would be without the `<code>` tag...

Is there a way to fix that?

Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/vxtqw33d/

Thanks for helping me to find the issue.

Comment: You need to HTML-escape your text

Comment: What do you mean? I'm talking about putting a whole webpage into a code tag.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571257/how-to-display-html-tags-as-text

Comment: The `code` element has no effect in interpreting tags.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to escape all characters, just escape the less-than and greater-than symbols which denote html elements (ie. <div>

You actually don't even have to do both sides, **as long as you escape the opening less-than ( < ) sign then your all set.**

---

The escape values are:

```
< is &lt;
> is &gt;
```

---

Not that its necessary in this case, but if you ever wanted to escape a large amount of code, there are free utilities online that can assist you with such tasks.  The first one I found on Google was http://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html

My personal favorite whenever I need to look up individual characters is http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the HTML via the `&lt;` and `&gt;` (means `<` and `>`).

If you are using PHP, this would be simple:

```
<?php
$code = '<strong>Foo</strong> Bar';
?>

<code><?php echo htmlentities($code); ?></code>
```

But you can achieve this with every dynamic language (google for `Html Encode LanguageName`).

If you're doing it with plain HTML, your best bet would be a WYSWIG Editor.