# Do not render some html tags

Tags: html

Here in my html page i want to show the html h1 tag as it is like below and my requirement is like to update those tags via jquery. but while trying this in my html tag is rendering. how to stop rendering the tag..! is there is any way to do this?

```
 <h1>Ganesh Putta</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571257/how-to-display-html-tags-as-text) and many, many others

Comment: it is there in document. My purpose is to change the tags dynamically, this is the reason i tagged javascript and jquery

Comment: @GaneshPutta In that case mention that as a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can escape HTML Entities like this:

```
&lt;h1&gt;Ganesh Putta&lt;/h1&gt;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xmp`.

```html
<xmp>
  <h1>Ganesh Putta</h1>
</xmp>
```

Comment: Any justification for down voting this answer?It will help me in improving it

Comment: Not my downvote, but [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp): "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." Also, <pre> and <code> don't work.

Comment: Yeah, even i was wondering why this question is also got downvotes? And even for your answer too?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use javascript with innerText.

```
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

and

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerText = '<h1>Ganesh Putta</h1>'
```