# How to put text in a p tag in html that looks like a tag

Tags: html, tags

I want to put the text  in a p tag in html. However, when the code runs, the  text is read as a tag, instead of just text. How do I get the computer to just read this as text.

```
<p class="body-copy-mini space"> 
    Change <name> tag's value 'Your App name' to whatever your app name is. <br>
                        Change <description> tag's value <br>
                        Change <author> tag's values <br>
                    </p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display HTML tags as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571257/how-to-display-html-tags-as-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s because HTML will treat ‘<‘ as opening tag and will try to render it. You need to convert all the applicable characters to their HTML entities to prevent this, for example 
For showing ‘<‘ you need to convert it to ‘&lt;’ and for ‘>’ you need to convert it to ‘&gt;’. There are some other characters which you will need to encode, some languages have built in function for this, example in PHP you can use ‘htmlentities()’ function.

try this

```
<p class="body-copy-mini space"> 
Change &lt;name&gt; tag's value 'Your App name' to whatever your app name is. <br>
                    Change &lt;description&gt; tag's value <br>
                    Change &lt;author&gt; tag's values <br>
                </p>
```

[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/5w1q8jbp/2/)