# Display HTML tags a string in inner html tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to display html tags in string format in inner html tag

I have following string

```
myString = "<span class="display-red"><a href="link"><span>ABC <a href=""></a>PQR</span><span>abc@gmail.com</span></a></span>"
```

This is my html tag in code (Here I want to render this html tag)

`<span [innerHtml]="myString"></span>`

Expected Output

```
ABC <a href=""></a>PQR
abc@gmail.com
```

I want to display some html tag as it is in my output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620271/how-to-put-text-in-a-p-tag-in-html-that-looks-like-a-tag/51620454 same question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the html you want to display, replace `<` with `&lt;` (or `>` with `&gt;`)

```html
myString = "<span class="display-red"><a href="link"><span>ABC &lt;a href="">&lt;/a>PQR</span><span>abc@gmail.com</span></a></span>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` instead of `<` and `&gt;` instead of `>`. You will get exactly what you want.
Solution:

```
myString = "<span class="display-red"><a href="link"><span>ABC &lt;a href=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;PQR</span><span>abc@gmail.com</span></a></span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `<` with `&lt;` and the `>` with `&gt;`. This will display it as regular text.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `<` with < and the `>` with >

```
myString = "<span class="display-red">ABC <a href="link"><span>&lt;a href=""&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</a>PQR</span><br><span>abc@gmail.com</span></span>"
```